# error C2661: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for win32 application development. Try to compile one existing c++ source file, which was already compiled in GCC (Linux).

```
#define DEFINE_PORT( parentClass, portClass, name, dataMember, callbacks,... )     
   do                                                                          
   {                                                                           
      dataMember = new portClass<parentClass>( *this, callbacks );            
      err = addProvidesPort( name, dataMember );                               
   }                                                                           
   while(0)
```

Here I'm invoking this function as:

```
   DEFINE_PORT( Service_impl,
                         ECPDataStoreProvidesPort,
                         ECP_DATA_STORE,
                         pECPDataStorePP,
                         &Service_impl::GetDataVersion,
                         &Service_impl::SetDataVersion,
                         &Service_impl::LoadData,
                         &Service_impl::StoreData,
                         &ECPService_impl::EnableBlobOperations,
                         &ECPService_impl::GetCurrentPersonalityIndex,
                         &ECPService_impl::SwapPersonalities,
                         &ECPService_impl::UpdateDataStoreBlob,
                         &ECPService_impl::ExtractDataStoreBlob,
                         &ECPService_impl::GetConstantPersonalityPtr );
```

`ECPDataStoreProvidesPort` class has constructor defined with 10 no of arguments.
Here VS compiler is not considering the variable length arguments and producing error as `portclass` has no overloaded constructor defined for two aruguments.

May anyone please help me out on this? What can be cause and How to handle this error?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `__VA_ARGS__` in the constructor call?

Comment: Is this the actual macro? Besides no `__VA_ARGS__`, there are also no `\ ` at the end of lines. This wouldn't work in GCC either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expansion, `callbacks` is set to `&Service_impl::GetDataVersion`, and the rest of the arguments (the `...`) are ignored.

The `...` arguments should be referred to as `__VA_ARGS__` in the macro body.

```
#define DEFINE_PORT( parentClass, portClass, name, dataMember, ... )\     
   do                                                               \          
   {                                                                \           
      dataMember = new portClass<parentClass>( *this, __VA_ARGS__ );\            
      err = addProvidesPort( name, dataMember );                    \           
   }                                                                \           
   while(0)
```